# Will I need to go through security again if I have a layover in Barcelona?

Tags: transit, airports, barcelona

I'm an American citizen and I'll be flying on one ticket/same airline from Naples, Italy to Copenhagen with a one hour layover in Barcelona. The connecting flight will be in the same terminal, but will I be able to just go to the gate of the next flight? Or do I have to go back through security? I only have a backpack so I won't be dealing with checked luggage.

Answer (score 2):

As you originate in a Schengen country and connect in a Schengen country, flying to another Schengen country, these should be treated as domestic flights and you should not have to go through security, as long as your flights arrive at and depart from the same terminal in Barcelona.

[Visit this website](http://www.aeropuertobarcelona-elprat.com/ingl/flight-connections-barcelona.htm) to see the official clearance procedures... excerpted material:

> For passengers in transit arriving and departing terminal T1 without their next boarding pass, self check-in kiosk are also available at the boarding area, but only for Air France-KLM, Austrian Airlines, Croatia Airlines and Lufthansa airlines.
>    T1, boarding area, corridor connecting floor 2 (self check-in kiosk: Air France-KLM, Austrian Airlines, Croatia Airlines and Lufthansa).
>    T1, boarding area B, floor 1 (self check-in kiosk: Air France-KLM, Austrian Airlines, Croatia Airlines and Lufthansa)
>    The passengers in transit terminal T1 without their next boarding pass. or passengers with luggage that is not checked to destination, must leave the boarding area and go to the check-in counter airline of their next flight.
>
> For passengers in transit arriving and departing terminal T2 (T2A, T2B or T2C), who already have their boarding pass, without luggage or baggage checked to destination, it is not necessary to leave the boarding area as the boarding areas of the terminal T2 (T2A, T2B and T2CC) are linked together by a corridor, and the maximum walking distance between them is 7 minutes.
>   The passengers in transit terminal T2 without their next boarding pass. or passengers with luggage that is not checked to destination, must leave the boarding area and go to the check-in counter airline of their next flight.

Comment: Schengen or not-Schengen have implications for whether one needs to go through _border control_, but could you detail how it influences _security screening_? Is this based on concrete knowledge of the layout of the terminals in Barcelona?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I've no specific experience with Barcelona, but every airport I've flown through (and I've flown through many) allows you to stay airside if you're making a domestic connection within the same terminal, and these flights will be treated as domestic for this purpose.  It's usually required to clear security after customs/immigration inspection because you usually have to reclaim your bags to clear the process.  Even that is changing, e.g. foreign to domestic connections in Calgary stay airside even through a Canada Customs visit.

Comment: http://www.aeropuertobarcelona-elprat.com/ingl/flight-connections-barcelona.htm Barcelona airport clearance procedures are here.

Comment: x @JimMacKenzie: I think your comments are colored by an expectation that your North American experience is representative of all the world. In Schengen-area airports the normal arrangement is that passengers who pass through inbound passport control _either_ end up in the airside Schengen concourse, _or_ have a choice between proceeding to the baggage reclaim (if they're at their final destination) or to the Schengen concourse (if they have their baggage checked through). Arrivals from a third country whose security is trusted do not have to go through screening during this process.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Precisely my point.  As an intra-Schengen passenger, this poster won't be subject to inbound passport control.

Comment: But @HenningMakholm's point is that passport control and security are different things.  In every Schengen airport I've been to (which doesn't include Barcelona), a traveler connecting between Schengen and non-Schengen flights usually does not have to clear security unless departing to the US (which requires extra security) or arriving from a country whose airport security is not trusted. This is true even though such a passenger does, of course, have to clear immigration controls.